# IAsyncEnumerable<> broken in VS 2019 preview 2 (Core 3.0 preview 1)

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, iasyncenumerable

After installing VS 2019 preview 2 i get a great number of errors. Error demo code:

```
public class Class1 {
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Get()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            await Task.Delay( 100 );
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

**and nothig more** (a new dll project)!
With preview 1 was ok.

The project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The error message is: 
*Error  CS0656  Missing compiler required member 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator'*

Object Browser shows the member in Collections.Generic.

Any ideas? Waiting for Core 3.0 preview 2?

Something like in [IAsyncEnumerable not working in C# 8.0 preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651322/iasyncenumerable-not-working-in-c-sharp-8-0-preview)
?

**Another problem with VS 2019 P2** (another project): 
Nullabilty warnings though NullableReferenceTypes line is there (in vs 19, preview 1 was ok):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    **<NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>**
```

The warning:
*Warning    CS8632  The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' context.*
Is project setting not enough? not global any more?

Comment: Yes, this is broken for the moment and it will be fixed. See "changes since preview 1" in [Mads' blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2019/01/24/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/), which mentions both issues.

Comment: Now, who voted to close *this* question? It's certainly reproducible and officially acknowledged

Comment: This is definitely a "something like this case" but you can't just add the missing classes this time. `IAsyncEnumerable` exists but the methods are different. You can't fake it with an extension method and any techniquest that would inject the missing method aren't worth it. You'll have to use a daily build or wait for Core 3.0 Preview 2. OTOH, given how volatile those previews are, might as well use the dailies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem 1

*Missing compiler required member 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator'*

### Solution

Install .NET Core v3.0.100-preview-010177

https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk#installers-and-binaries

### Explanation

There was a breaking change to `IAsyncEnumerable` from .NET Core 3 Preview 1 to .NET Core Preview 2

> Async streams
>
> We changed the shape of the IAsyncEnumerable interface the compiler expects! This brings the compiler out of sync with the interface provided in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 1, which can cause you some amount of trouble. However, .NET Core 3.0 Preview 2 is due out shortly, and that brings the interfaces back in sync.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2019/01/24/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/

## Problem 2

*The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' context*

### Solution

Change`<NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>`

to

`<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>`

### Explanation

This is a breaking change from VS2019 Preview 1 to VS2019 Preview 2.

> Nullable reference types
>
> We’ve added more options to control nullable warnings both in source (through #nullable and #pragma warning directives) and at the project level. We also changed the project file opt-in to enable.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2019/01/24/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/

Comment: 1000 thanks!    (i) your answer is logically clear and perfectly structured; (ii) it is correct -- you saved me.

Comment: Thanks @me-on-stov! Don’t forget to mark it as “Answered” to help devs with the same question in the future 

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 Preview 2.0 [just came out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2019/01/29/announcing-net-core-3-preview-2/)

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Has this been re-broken in Preview 4, as I have this issue today after upgrading from Preview 3 to 4?

Comment: Hi @PaulManzotti! Since @me-on-stov's original question is focused on Preview 2, go ahead and open a new question for Preview 4 and share the link below 

Answer (score 3):

Replacing

`<NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>`

With

`<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>`

Fixed my issues with nullable reference types.

**EDIT:**

It may be worth having both options in the .csproj file as the dotnet Docker images has not yet been updated and will fail as it does not recognize the new nullable reference type tag

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 16.2 the property name changed to `Nullable` which is simpler and aligns with the command line argument.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```